# Load an embed excel file temporarily to work with

Tags: c#, excel, embed

I tried to do this for two hours but I'm not finding anything that is working.

basically I want to load and embed Excel file in C# but but I don't how.

```
Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
objExcel.Visible = true;
objExcel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;

                 
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 
                "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

I don't know how to get out the embed file in a way that I'm able to continue working with it. I need a way that my embed file is temporarily stored and I know its filename to open it.

Please help me I'm desperate.

Edit:
For clarification I embedded the document in the solution explorer of Visual Studios changing build option in the properties to embedded Resource.

[Here you can see how I embedded the Document.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYDCi.png)

Comment: "embed" could mean several things. Where is it embedded?

Comment: I edited my post so you can see how i did it i hope you can help me :)